# Looking for a way to condense this piece of code

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I am trying to learn ways to condense code that I am writing. The goal is to print out the objects of list, sorted in either reverse or regular order, 'lchar' one line at a time. This code does the job, but I believe there is a way to clean it up.

```
   lchar =  list()
   for key,val in list(wd.items()):
      lchar.append((val,key))
      lchar.sort(reverse=True)

   for key,val in lchar:
   print(key,val)
```

Is there a way to condense this code so I can sort it at the same line I am appending it to the list 'lchar', and print the tuples line by line in the same block of code?

Comment: You really should worry about less superficial things. For example, it is much more important to move the sorting *outside the loop* so it doesn't sort unnecessarily for ever item. Also, stop needlessly using `list(wd.items()`... why are you creating a list there? This is more important than how condensed your code is

Comment: Why would you want to sort at the same time you append? You only need to sort once, after all of the items are in the list. There is no need to sort on every iteration of the loop. Also, trying to do everything in one line does not make your code better, it normally makes your code worse.

Answer (score 0):

No need to insert each element one by one. Simply retrieve the items from the dictionary, sort them and assign them. Note that sorted creates a list. The map reverses the order of the elements in the list.

```
lchar =  sorted(map(lambda p: (p[1],p[0]), wd.items()))
```

You can also use a comprehension, but I find them less readable:

```
lchar = sorted(((v,k) for k, v in wd.items()))
```

It will a create the list of pairs that you can then print

```
for key,val in lchar:
   print(key,val)
```